# Autoplay Video with Sound

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in HTML and just want to write a page with a little video and a text.
I want to autoplay the video but with sound. Since it's only possible to autoplay without sound I assume that I need javascript.

This is my code so far

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="generic.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="" class="myVideo" id="myVideo">
            <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
          </video> 
    </body>
</html>
```

css file:

```
video {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Is it somehow possible or am I forced to use a button to autoplay?

Comment: Google has changed autoplay policy so user have to interact with website before autoplay to allow sound, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct, But here are google's poilcy
Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:

Muted autoplay is always allowed.

- Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
- User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
- On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been
  crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound. The
  user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed
  the PWA on desktop.

**TRY INTREACT WITH SNIPPET BEFORE VIDEO LOADS**

```css
video {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="generic.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="" class="myVideo" id="myVideo">
            <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
          </video> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Above snippet is working just click quickly before video loads in snippets result

Comment: could you maybe paste it on pastebin or so

Comment: Your code is correct this is all about user interaction before autoplay to play video with sound.

Answer (score 1):

A hacky trick I've seen people use is add an `iframe` containing an autoplay material before the element itself thus forcing subsequent elements to have audio. You can check something like it done [here](https://olafwempe.com/how-to-enable-audio-and-video-autoplay-with-sound-in-chrome-and-other-browsers-in-2019/).

```
<iframe src="SOME_EMPTY_VIDEO_WITH_SILENCE_URL" type="video/mp4" allow="autoplay" id="video" style="display:none"></iframe>
<video autoplay>
     <source src="ACTUAL_VIDEO_URL" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Still, like I said, this is a nasty hack.

Comment: Does this still work? I've tried but it doesn't look like it does :( My video won't play unless I add `muted` to it!

Answer (score 1):

As per New Policy - https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#new-behaviors. There should be User Interactions to AutoPlay any Videos with Sounds.

Here is an example solution for the same:-

[HTML5 Video autoplay with sound unmuted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70719678/html5-video-autoplay-with-sound-unmuted/76471447#76471447)

Hope it works for you and in case it is a different in which you struck then let me know.