# How does YouTube start a video unmuted skipping JavaScript restriction about unmuted videos?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I noticed that if you open a YouTube link, the video will start autoplaying with sound, even if I haven't interacted with the page.

For what I know, [the browser needs the user to interact with the page to allow unmuted videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405988/autoplay-video-with-sound).

How does YouTube that? How can I implement it to my webpage?

Comment: Just in chrome? For me that's not the case in Firefox

Comment: Yes, just in Chrome, you've got the reason, in FIrefox it doesn't work...