# How to auto play an unmuted video in HTML

Tags: html, html5-video

I am using a video tag and I want ot to auto play when the page loads but it only auto play when it is muted. How to auto play a video which is not muted.

Comment: This answer might help, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65406021/18333498

Comment: Another similar question that could help: [HTML5 Video autoplay with sound unmuted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70719678/html5-video-autoplay-with-sound-unmuted)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="yourvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="yourvideo.extension" type="video/extension">
</video>
```

Comment: This might not work if your browser does not support this tipe of code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).