# Enable video autoplay with sound

Tags: html, audio, video, attributes, autoplay

I've searched a lot on how to enable video `autoplay` with sound works in the html.

- **[Autoplay only works with muted](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/autoplay-video-attribute-not-working/442167)**
- **[Not woring in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser)**

The thing is, when the `autoplay` is followed by `muted` attribute, the autoplay works just fine.

I have this video, and was suppose to autoplay, without user interaction(`controls`) and with sound on.

```js
//start condition (jquery)

    //$('video').removeAttr('muted');
    
//end condition
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <video class="childhood-img" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" playsinline="playsinline" type="video/mov" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDLn5-zSQQI" >
  </video>
</div>
```

My dout is, how can **enable autoplay**, **with sound on** and **without `controls`** abritute?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autoplay Video with Sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405988/autoplay-video-with-sound)

Comment: I tried to implement the trick from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405988/autoplay-video-with-sound)**, but did not work 

Answer (score 0):

Having autoplay with sound is not possible anymore without an user interacting with the page. Browser vendors disabled this feature because it annoyed a lot of people and it was not safe in working environments.

Interesting ressource: https://jamonserrano.github.io/state-of-autoplay/